# Why could CreateFile fail on a network drive

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have one installation that behaves VERY oddly... Every time we try to copy something on a network drive we check accessibility with code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.TestAccess;
var fn : string;
    hdl : THandle;
    res : boolean;
    dir : string;
    flags : Cardinal;
begin
     dir := edDir.Text;
     flags := FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN; 
     fn := FindUnusedFileName( IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( dir ) + IntToStr( Random(10000) ) + '.tst' );

     memLog.Lines.Add('Try to create file: ' + fn);

     hdl := CreateFile( PChar(fN), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_DELETE, nil, CREATE_NEW,
                        flags, 0 );

     res := hdl <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
     if not res then
     begin
          memLog.Lines.Add('Error: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
     end
     else
         memLog.Lines.Add('Success');

     if res then
        CloseHandle(hdl);
end;
```

where `memLog` is a `TMemo` and `edDir` is simply an edit field.

Now here is the strange part... I get an access denied on that system meaning uploading will fail most of the time (most of the time is the strange part here).

Another thing is that in a first attempt I used the JvDirectoryEdit control. In that case the result is twofold... If I enter the directory (UNC Path) there without a backslash I get the access denied too. If I enter a final backslash and the combo box window pops up showing the content (aka directories) in that folder it finally works!!!

So... First: has anyone a clue what the problem might be and do I something wrong here?

Comment: Note that without a call to Randomize() calls to Random() return the same sequence of numbers from program start for every run.

Comment: You simply cannot expect having write access in every folder of any network share - check if you can create a file AND write to it manually. You cannot expect that the current working directory is at where you think it is - always check what [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) returns.

Comment: How is your `FindUnusedFileName` finding which file name is available? It is possible it might be causing you these problems. Also have you perhaps considered of using [GetTempFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettempfilenamea) for retrieving the uniquely named filenames.

Comment: First... Randomize is called somewhere else so no the numbers are random. The FinUnusedFilename just adds a counter to the file name until FileExists returns false.
And ... the filees are flagged as FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE which means that the file is removed by the OS after closehandle or when the app closes.
I actually suspect that there is some network share magic happening and or a Virus scanner that thinks that this type of access check is bad. 
Is there anyone out with some experience? I don't have any more background but it would be highly appreciated for some directions.

Comment: If you create  [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I will be able to try to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this procedure in the past to check if a directory is read-only, maybe it can be useful:

```
 FUNCTION DirRO(NomeCartella : String) : Boolean;
      VAR VarFile : TextFile;
          NomCart : String;
    BEGIN
          Result := False;
          If NomeCartella[Length(NomeCartella)]='\'
             Then NomCart := NomeCartella
             Else NomCart := NomeCartella+'\';

          Try AssignFile(VarFile,NomCart+'^ghi.kol');
              {$I-}
              Rewrite(VarFile);
              {$I-}
              If IOResult<>0 Then
                 Begin
                 Result := True;
                 Exit;
                 End;
              CloseFile(VarFile);
              Erase(VarFile);
              Except Result := True;
          End;
    END;
```